# simple php script to retrieve google keyword search completion

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve just the search completion shown in Google search result for any keyword. For example the search completion for

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=google+keyword+search

is 48,400,000 (Results 1 - 10 of about 48,400,000 for google keyword search)

I tried to use CURL but fail to retrieve the search result page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Im sure it is forbidden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to do anything nearly that complicated.

Just use their search API

```
$search = 'google keyword search';
$results = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=' . urlencode( $search ) ) );

echo $results->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount;
```

Comment: Ok - I'll bite.  This answer is nearly a year old and suddenly a down vote?  Did the API change and this answer is out of date?  Help me out here you downvoter person you.

Comment: 3 years after, working like a charm, spend half day yesterday looking for a solution and this one was the winner.

Comment: The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, the link you posted is incorrect, that will just get google.com, because the hash value is never part of the request URI. It should be http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=google+keyword+search

Second, Google blocks crawlers from accessing anything from `/search` with robots.txt. Whether CURL pays attention to this or not I don't know. However, it's very likely that Google blocks access from unknown sources. I guess you could try and set the user-agent to match a web browser, though that is kind of deceiving...

Comment: The link works.  Also, curl does not pay attention to robots.txt, that's left to the client's discretion.  A valid user-agent is not required to make a request, although including one will probably keep your IP from being banned a little longer.