# Using CURL with Google

Tags: php, curl

I want to CURL to Google to see how many results it returns for a certain search.

I've tried this:

```
  $url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$strSearch."&hl=en&start=0&sa=N";
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

But it just returns a 405 Method Allowed google error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple php script to retrieve google keyword search completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784114/simple-php-script-to-retrieve-google-keyword-search-completion)

Comment: This is not really a duplicate.  The other question is similar, but the answer is completely different than what this OP is looking for.  The answer to the other questions uses neither CURL nor the normal Google query URL.

Comment: Irrelevant.  He's trying CURL and normal Google because that's what he knows.  I'm saying that neither CURL nor the "normal Google query URL" are necessary to get the desired value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a GET request instead of a POST request. That is, get rid of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Or even better, use their [well defined search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) instead of screen-scraping.

Comment: Duh! Of course! I think I'll stick to screen scraping though.

Comment: Why would you stick to screen scraping, which will be brittle to the page's UI changes, when there's a well-defined API available that has what you want?

Comment: The API has limitations, such as only returning the first 30 results.  Scrapping Google is a very common thing.

Comment: Common or not common, it's against the Google Terms of Service.

Comment: Once Google starts to pay its proper share of taxes people will show more respect for their terms of service.

Comment: @RidIculous: Yeah, right. I'm sure that's totally the true reason people don't care about their terms.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. My point is that a company of this size and scope should lead by example.

Answer (score 4):

Scrapping Google is a very easy thing to do.  However, if you don't require more than the first 30 results, then the [search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) is preferable (as others have suggested).  Otherwise, here's some sample code.  I've ripped this out of a couple of classes that I'm using so it might not be totally functional as is, but you should get the idea.

```
function queryToUrl($query, $start=null, $perPage=100, $country="US") {
    return "http://www.google.com/search?" . $this->_helpers->url->buildQuery(array(
        // Query
        "q"     => urlencode($query),
        // Country (geolocation presumably)
        "gl"    => $country,
        // Start offset
        "start" => $start,
        // Number of result to a page
        "num"   => $perPage
    ), true);
}

// Find first 100 result for "pizza" in Canada
$ch = curl_init(queryToUrl("pizza", 0, 100, "CA"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,      $this->getUserAgent(/*$proxyIp*/));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,      4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Note: `$this->_helpers->url->buildQuery()` is identical to [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) except that it will drop empty parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Google Ajax API.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/

See [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1474740.aspx) for how to get the number of results. While it refers to c# libraries, it might give you some pointers.

Comment: this API is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Before scrapping data please read https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?rd=1

Against google terms

Automated traffic includes:

Sending searches from a robot, computer program, automated service, or search scraper
Using software that sends searches to Google to see how a website or webpage ranks on Google

Answer (score -4):

CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => ($post)? "POST" : "GET"