# Scraping data using CURL

Tags: php, dom, curl

I just read [Using CURL with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968866/using-curl-with-google/27211862)

but google allow me only for 4 and 5 times after that i receive this message instead search results.

**To continue, please type the characters below:
please enable images
ut this page
Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot. Why did this happen?**

I am doing like that using PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.google.com/search?q='.$keywords.'&num=100&start='.$i);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
//further operation here
}
```

Is there any way to avoid google to display this message?

Comment: That message specifically targets spiders such as yours. TOS et al, no workaround, use [one of the APIs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) instead.

Comment: CAPTHAS like that are used to prevent scrappers or spiders like yours. An option is to specify a user agent while making the request so that you mimick an actual web browser. Then your request needs to be spaced and not too frequent.

If all you're interested in is getting search results from google, you can use the API directly

Before scrapping websites always check to see you're not violating the T&C

Comment: i recive: 

Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot. Why did this happen?