# retrieving Google search results

Tags: php, search

i read your post on

*[simple php script to retrieve google keyword search completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784114/simple-php-script-to-retrieve-google-keyword-search-completion)*

and i was wondering how would you go 'echo' the next page?
here's my script..

> $search = 'query';
>
> $x = json_decode( file_get_contents(
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='
>   . urlencode( $search ) ) );
>
> echo
>   $x->responseData->results[0]->url;

i was able to 'echo' out the url, i am stucked in going to the next page and 'echo' out the next url's

thanks sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change the index:

```
echo $x->responseData->results[1]->url;
```

To loop through all:

```
foreach ($x->responseData->results as $r) {
    echo $r->url, "\n";
}
```

You can inspect the complete result with `var_dump($x);`.

To retrieve another page of results, you can use the `start` parameter, e.g.:

```
$x = json_decode(
    file_get_contents(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=4&q='
    . urlencode( $search )));
```

You can request 8 results instead of 4 with `rsz=large`.

Comment: it is displaying the results..in the script. it will only display about 4 results..

what i wanted to know is how to display the results on the next page

Comment: ohai thanks :)
i actually did that already. i was enlightened after reading 'start=4'
what i did is 'start=1' where currentpageindex is still 0 haha xD

Comment: Here is the documentation http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje

Comment: may i ask another question? is there a way to know the maximum pages? i tried to count($x->pages) and it only returns 8

Comment: @kapi There's `$x->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount`. But it's estimated. If you wanted to retrieve all results, you'd have to advance `start` until you received nothing back.

Comment: thanks very much @arte..thats what im actually doing right now :)

Comment: it seems like it returns only limited results. like when i search for the word 'kapitanluffy' the search ends in 'start=56'

wherein google it exceeds up to start=200+

Comment: are there any other way to get more results??

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking to interface with Google and stumbled on this solution, the code above now returns this response: `object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["responseData"]=> NULL ["responseDetails"]=> string(143) "The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)" ["responseStatus"]=> int(403) }`

**Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)**   I hope this saves someone some time!