# Read Google Search results into PHP array?

Tags: php, api, url, search

In short, I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
$results_array = google("search terms"); // returns array of URLs
```

So, for example, if my search terms were "cat videos" my $results_array[0] might be a Youtube URL, and $results_array[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436525/retrieving-google-search-results) might be on Vimeo.

I've seen the Google Custom Search API, but they all require complex JSON transformations, ATOM, REST or some other system which is overly complicated for what I'm trying to do.

Are there any simple solutions out there?

**EDIT: I found it, thanks to another post**

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436525/retrieving-google-search-results) I was able to figure it out.  In short, I simply used the following:

```
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents( 
          'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='.
           urlencode($search)));

echo $results->responseData->results[$resultNumber]->url;
```

I'm a bit surprised and disapointed by the downvotes -- it seems to be quite a common question with, indeed, quite a simple answer.  This does involve JSON, but it's completely transparent to the user.  Perhaps an even more accurate solution to what I asked would be:

```
function google($query) {
    $results = json_decode(file_get_contents( 
          'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='.
           urlencode($search)));

    return $results->responseData->results
}
```

Comment: How is JSON overly complicated? Seems like the first choice for your implementation. Definitely less complicated than something like parsing HTML search results...

Comment: google does not like anything that tries to bypass their api, so if you'll try to make direct requests and to parse the results - your host might be banned.

Answer (score 3):

if you wan to get video results then you can try this.

```
//replace space between words with +
$query = "cat+video"; 
$start = 0;
/*
this url will give you json response with 4 results each time.
u have to change the $start like 0, 4, 8,...
use json_decode() and get it in array
*/

$url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/video?v=1.0&q='.$query.'&start='.$start
```

hope it will be helpful.